# Need assistance from MATLAB point of view

Tags: matlab, digital-communications, gaussian

In my work there are three entities i.e, Tag , reader and RF source. In which for a single bit (0 or 1) from tag towards reader there are 40 consecutive complex gaussian signals at reader . **How to model this in MATLAB so as to get 40 consecutive complex gaussian signals.** Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adopted from the Matlab doc:
    N=40; 
    mu = ones(1,2);
    sigma = eye(2);
    R = chol(sigma);
    z = (mu + randn(N,2)*R)*[1; 1j]

Comment: can you explain the code. I understood about mu,z and sigma but why R .